# Shopify Remix App: Storefront API Undefined With AppProxy

Tags: shopify

I have an odd behaviour that I cannot quite understand:
I used the [shopify remix app template](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix) to create an extension that allows a customer to interact with our business backend through the store's frontend. I achieved this through a route that first makes a request to our business backend and follows that up with requests to the storefront api.

When running it locally it works just fine, but when I deploy it to our dev store, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'graphql')
    at getImageByVariant (/app/build/index.js:583:40)
    at action5 (/app/build/index.js:575:28)
    at Object.callRouteActionRR (/app/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/data.js:35:16)
    at callLoaderOrAction (/app/node_modules/@remix-run/router/router.ts:4020:16)
    at submit (/app/node_modules/@remix-run/router/router.ts:3133:16)
    at queryImpl (/app/node_modules/@remix-run/router/router.ts:3068:22)
    at Object.queryRoute (/app/node_modules/@remix-run/router/router.ts:3018:18)
    at handleResourceRequestRR (/app/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/server.js:296:20)
    at requestHandler (/app/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/server.js:104:18)
```

The Dockercontainer is running in the cloud, I set the correct values for the environment variables for scope, shopify_key, shopify_secret and app_url and the app deploys as normal. In the partner dashboard I checked the urls => all conforming to the container's address including the app proxy.

I installed it on the target shop, added the app-block to a page and opened it in preview. That is when the error occurred.

This is the endpoint in question:

```
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import { authenticate } from "../shopify.server";
const HTV_API_BASE_URL = process.env.HTV_API_BASE_URL


export const action = async ({ request }) => {

  var request_params = await request.json()
  var token = request_params.token

  let data = await fetch(HTV_API_BASE_URL + '/customers/v1/access', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
            'X-Htv-User-Token' : token
        }
    }).then(response => {

      return response.json();
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    return {
      "status" : "error"
  }
  });
  // if we received correct data, enhance dataset with shopify data
  if (!!data && data.status == "OK") {
    let main_product = data.token_data.data.proposed_changes
    console.log(main_product)
    console.log(main_product.alternative)
    console.log(main_product.alternative.molecule_group)
    main_product.imageUrl =  await getImageByVariant(request, main_product.shop_identifier)
    main_product.molecule_group = main_product.alternative.molecule_group

    let alternative = main_product.alternative
    alternative.imageUrl =  await getImageByVariant(request, alternative.shop_identifier)
  }
  return data;
}

async function getImageByVariant(request, variant_id) {
  // gets the image url from shopify
  const { storefront } = await authenticate.public.appProxy(request);
  try {
    var shopify_variant_id = "gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/" + variant_id
    const response = await storefront.graphql(
      `#graphql
        query($id: ID!) {
          node(id: $id) {
            ... on ProductVariant {
              id
              product {
                featuredImage {
                  url
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }`,
      {
        variables: {
          "id" : shopify_variant_id
        },
      },
    );
    // const responseJson = await response.json();

    let data =  await response.json();
    return json({
      "image_url" : data.data.node?.product?.featuredImage?.url
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return json({
      "image_url" : null
    });
  }
};
```

I found a lot of very similar problems, all pertaining to { admin } = authenticate.public.appProxy, but none to storefront. I presume this is due to some problem with access rights, but this is the scopes and app proxy definition from the toml:

```
[app_proxy]
url = REDACTED FOR SAFETY
subpath = "oos"
prefix = "apps"

[access_scopes]
scopes = "read_products,unauthenticated_read_product_listings"
```

Can someone spot the mistake?

I tried reinstalling the app in the store, I redeployed it to the server, I ran the app with the same config except the urls from my local machine (which worked) and then used the same config with corrected urls, => nothing changes.
I cannot seem to get access.

For reference, this is the log of the request towards the business server:
oos?shop=*******&logged_in_customer_id=&path_prefix=%2Fapps%2Foos&timestamp=1708522357&signature=dc9b8432b9fb75138d8dd9c9c18e3ae3638c7581c27b19e97973f2ab09cc74a7